# Convergence of the series $ \sum_0^{\infty} 1/(1+x^n)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I found it easy to show that this series converges for $x > 1$, and that it diverges for $-1 \leq x < 1 $ but I haven't been able to show anything for $x <-1$, does it diverge or converge? how do I show that?

Comment: What tests for convergence do you know?

Comment: Do you know ratio test?

Comment: Just check for absolute convergence; it reduces to the case for $x>1$ (essentially).

Comment: Abel's, Weistrauss M test, leibniz criterion, ratio and root tests, integral, kummer's, Gauss, Raabe's.

Comment: Alternating series test?

Answer (score 0):

It converges:

Note that $\frac{1}{|1+x^n|}\leq\frac{1}{|x|^n-1}\leq \frac{C}{|x|^n}$ for sufficiently large C when $|x|>1$. Now comparison to the Geometric Series will complete the proof.

Comment: ok so that proves that it is absolutely convergent for $ |x| > 1$ right ? what about uniform convergence ? can I conclude uniform convergence from absolute convergence in some way?

Comment: You can conclude uniform convergence via the M-test on $\{|x|\geq r\}$ for any $r>1$, as on this set $\frac{1}{|x|^n}\leq\frac{1}{r^n}$. However, there isn't uniform convergence on $\{|x|>1\}$